# I'd like to use async function in useEffect but it ain't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my side project and I'd like to use an async function that returns users data.
So I declared the async function outside of useEffect and try to setState in the async function.

when I console.log res in then block, it shows the result I expected but when I console.log outside of async getData function, it won't work

why setUsersData(setState) doesn't work as i expected?

```
const FeedPage = () => {
  const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState()

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    await Goodlogging.inquireFeed().then((res) => {
    // when i console.log here it returns as i expected...
      console.log(res.data)
      setUsersData(res.data)
    })
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    // try to console.log data but it returns undefined ...
    console.log('usersData:', usersData)
  }, [usersData])

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [getData])
```

Comment: `await Goodlogging.inquireFeed().then((res) => {` should just be `const { data } = await GoodLogging.inquireFeed();`. Don't mix `.then` with `await`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useEffect` callback can't be `async`, but you can declare a self-executable async function inside.

Also, side note, don't use `promise` syntax with `async/await` syntax.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   (async () => {
     const res = await Goodlogging.inquireFeed()
     // when i console.log here it returns as i expected...
     console.log(res.data)
     setUsersData(res.data)

   })()
 }, [getData])
```

Comment: While that is correct, he OP isn't using an async callback to useEffect....

Comment: Yes, he doesn't, but this is his goal, that is what I understood from the title and description of the question, he want execute an `async` function inside `useEffect` after the component has been mounted.

Comment: Apparently it was, +1